# Typescript: adding aliases via `Object.defineProperty` to an array type

Tags: typescript

If I have an array for this sake `['test', 'test2', 'test3']`, I'm adding aliases to it using `Object.defineProperty()` that are defined in a different array `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

Here is my current (shortened) example that does not allow me to access the defined property on the returned array.

How can I have typescript recognise that there are defined properties on this array that match the values of the array `['a', 'b', 'c']`?

```
const aliasArr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const applyAliases = <Alias extends string[], Values extends any[]>(aliases: Alias) => (arr: Values) => {
    const definition = [...arr];
    aliases.forEach((key, i) =>
        Object.defineProperty(definition, key, {
            enumerable: false,
            get(): Values[number] {
                return this[i];
            },
        })
    );
    return definition as typeof arr & { [P in keyof Alias]: Values[number] };
};

const applied = applyAliases<typeof aliasArr, string[]>(aliasArr)(['test', 'test2', 'test3']);

const test = applied.a // Error, property 'a' does not exist on type string[]
```

Comment: Just noticed my own mistake in this, swapping `[P in keyof Alias]` to `[key in Alias[number]]` fixes this. However I feel that this is still not a good solution as `applied.x` does not throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already figured out that applying mapped type to array results in array, so
`{ [P in keyof Alias]: Values[number] }` should be `{ [P in Alias[number]]: Values[number] }` or `Record<Alias[number], Values[number]>`.

The missing part is restricting `Alias[number]` to desired keys instead of just `string[]`. This can be achieved by defining `aliasArr` as readonly tuple:

```
const aliasArr = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const; // aliasArr is of type readonly ["a", "b", "c"]

const applyAliases = <Alias extends ReadonlyArray<string>>(aliases: Alias) => <Values extends any[]>(arr: Values) => {
    const definition = [...arr];
    aliases.forEach((key, i) =>
        Object.defineProperty(definition, key, {
            enumerable: false,
            get(): Values[number] {
                return this[i];
            },
        })
    );
    return definition as Values & Record<Alias[number], Values[number]>;
};

const applied = applyAliases(aliasArr)(['test', 'test2', 'test3']);

const test = applied.a // now OK

applied.x // Property 'x' does not exist on type 'string[] & { a: string; b: string; c: string; }'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgGwJZwgQQE4ZgXhgbQHI5CAaGQgIzIuEIF14IZRIoBuGAei-mVUzYkzEADMYUAJ4AHAKYwMsuABNwCSQQBEcTeU2VdMTcE30AUGdbR406erT8Is5ngA8DlM1kAPKLLDKzABKSqpg9lhwkq7QGEhgAOYAfEkAFIiezgBcMB6oAJS4STCuAGqIAK7OMD5+AcxwYJL49GlwWDnlCFUQhTjFAN5mMCzg1sqyovFIUEjguAQAdMvtGPTsw3yZEIuiIBgAonDAABapqQDWspLkSH1JmyMA8pQAVrLAUIsTU2CyAAoYEByDBSVI-aazcDkK43GBDEaImpgCoAW1kGDglAQshyokQTlIj0RCVkUFS+U6lWc+BRqMoGMYCKRiMUUAqGDAEhOwnwSHWxJGAF8iUihflNvkNiM2RyuRCwDM5lzUDAuj0YAAyGAhUAYZTuRy0tEMtbkdU0umm1obIUbSxjWBwWzIWTKBbOuySPJOCDpRyCfKpIh+aA0QihqAAJnDkYAzAwpRYrLBIx6XUg3Ys4NxeGAQAB3GBPADSFk9ruUi28uZggOBGKkFG8hBgqmq+dgPmEsHmUjkFFi8QSLS18PgOSHiU4lEnUDi05Yc4XCU4QsIZiAA)

---

** Second generic parameter moved to inner function, so typescript will be able to infer it properly

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was hoping to do.